# Getting a compiling error: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to add(E) as a member of the raw type ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, compilation

I am developing a textbased RPG. In one of the classes there is an ArrayList that handles save and load game. There is both Integers and Strings in the ArrayList.

This is a String: `saveGame.add(p.getName());`
And this is a Integer: `saveGame.add(p.getCurrLoc());`

Every variable that is adding an element to the list receive a warning like this one:

> D:\Backup\RPG\src\rpg\Player.java:86: warning: [unchecked] unchecked
>   call to add(E) as a member of the raw type ArrayList
>           getInventory().add(item);   where E is a type-variable:
>       E extends Object declared in class ArrayList

Code:

```
public class Data {

private ArrayList saveGame;

//Sparar en ny rad i sparfilen
public void writeData(String in) {        

    try {
        FileWriter out = new FileWriter("Savegame.txt", true);
        out.write(in + "\n");
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Data.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public void save(Player p) {
    clearData();


    saveGame = new ArrayList();
    saveGame.add(p.getName());                  
    saveGame.add(p.getCurrLoc());               
    saveGame.add(p.getStrength());              
    saveGame.add(p.getConstitution());         
    saveGame.add(p.getDexterity());             
    saveGame.add(p.getHitpoints());            
    saveGame.add(p.getLevel());                
    saveGame.add(p.getxP());                    
    saveGame.add(p.getxPToLvlUp());             
    saveGame.add(p.getArmorClass());           
    saveGame.add(p.getNrOfPotions());           
    saveGame.add(p.getEqWeapon().getName());   


    for(Object element : p.getInventory()) {
        if(element instanceof Weapon) {
            saveGame.add(((Weapon) element).getName());
        } else if(element instanceof Item) {
            saveGame.add(((Item) element).getName());
        } else if(element instanceof Armor) {
            saveGame.add(((Armor) element).getName());
        }
    }

    for(Object element : saveGame) {
        writeData(element.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use generics.

Comment: A warning is not an error.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, this is a warning, not an error.  You can still run your code in this state.  It just opens the door to many potential problems.

Basically, you should define your list so that you know what type each and every element is.  This is done using generics.

So you can declare your list as a list of strings as follows:

```
ArrayList<String> saveGame = new ArrayList<String>();
```

This means you can only add strings to the list.  However, it also means that getter methods will always return strings, so no casting is ever necessary.

Comment: Then I have to convert the integers, like `saveGame.add(p.getCurrLoc());` when I add a value to the list. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Ah, I didn't see the integers there.  But there's always `String.valueOf()` to help you with that.

Comment: I am unsure how to do thios correctly, I tried to write it this way:
`saveGame.add String.valueOf(p.getCurrLoc());`
but recieved errors.

Answer (score 1):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I solved the problem like this:

```
ArrayList<Object> saveGame = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest versions of Java allow you to specify the type(s) of object that you will place in your ArrayList using a syntax like this ArrayList. This allows the compiler to check the types of any object you add to the list at compile and execution time, and allows for safer and less error-prone code

If you use the legacy versions as you have done (without the ), then the compiler cannot make this check so it gives you a warning.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Could you please give me an example of how to implement this in my code. 

this is a String       
      `saveGame.add(p.getName());`               
and this a Integer    
      `saveGame.add(p.getCurrLoc());`

Comment: Sorry, I just now saw you had a follow up question. As others have stated, the warning is not an error you can ignore it as long as you understand its purpose as stated above.

Comment: But if you want to remove it, just define the ArrayList using the appropriate type, for example,  ArrayList<String>.  If you plan to put objects of different types, then use the highest common super class or Object as someone else stated (ArrayList<Object>).